# Why does lord shiva like abhishekam?

Tags: shiva, rituals, worship

At many places I have heard that lord shiva likes abhishekam so much and also he blesses the devotees with their desires. Why does shiva like abhishekam so much?

Comment: Shiva is the static omnipresent invisible Atman, the seer. Only united with material Shakti, Shiva is able to manifest the visible earth. Now, milk represents purity and enlightenment. Thats why Brahmins were given cows  by ancient Aryan Kings. So, one who does abhishekam of Shiva with milk is clearing his own impurities and therefore his desires are fulfilled due to removal of personal sins. Similar is the abhishekam of Sun, the light with water called Surya namaskar as nourishing purifying water/milk is the direct form of dynamic Shakti.